# Java Playframework redirect to external url with Json payload

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I have 3 applications. all 3 are written in play java.
Users of App2 and App3 will be authenticated using App-1 only.
So app2 and app3 will send the callback url to app1.
App-1 should authenticate and send the authtoken and userdetails as json format. (Similiar way of google oauth).
I have completed below items,

1. App-2 and App-3 successfully redirected to app-1 for authentication.
2. App-1 successfully generated the authtoken and user details as json.

But how App-1 could redirect to callback url with json content. 
How do i sent the json data in play's redirect(callbackurl).

Please guide me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP redirection with a different body is [not possible](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect).  You can however include the JSON as a query string in the redirection URL. This is how `OAuth2` services including Facebook does it.